# Highcharts - how to export chart with a custom legend?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to export a chart with my custom legend.

How to do it in a native way?

I mean I don't want to use external libraries, like 'html2canvas' or etc.

here is my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/sergeymnet/4kqgdc5L/9/):

```
chart.renderer.text('custom legend V1', 90, 90)
        .css({color: '#4572A7', fontSize: '16px'})
        .add();


window.takeScreenShot = function() {

  chart.exportChart({
    filename: 'targetFilename'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart is recreated for exporting, so if you want to add some custom elements, you need to use the `load` event:

```
chart: {
  ...,
  events: {
    load: function() {
      this.renderer.text('custom legend V1', 90, 90)
        .css({
          color: '#4572A7',
          fontSize: '16px'
        })
        .add();
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dsa8uyz3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load